# Problem removing a package "dpkg: error processing package chromium-browser (--remove):"

Tags: 20.04, package-management, dpkg, uninstall, error-handling

```
$ sudo apt remove chromium-browser

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chromium-browser
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 164 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package chromium-browser (--remove):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 chromium-browser
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Try reinstalling with `sudo apt install —reinstall chromium-browser` then try removing again.